# Multipart response in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, multipart

Does Laravel 4 support multipart response?
I need to output and also process, parse this kind of data. JSON combined with base64 image blobs.

Just image there is some route handling request like "something.com/api/v1/get-all" action in controller should respond with multipart.

Whats the best practice in Laravel framework?

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=.............................103832778631715

--.............................103832778631715
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__json_data__";
Content-Type: application/json;
{
    "item": {
        "uuid": "12345-523462362-252636",
        "title": "Title"
    }
}
.............................103832778631715
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imageFile"; filename="someImage.jpg"
Content-type: application/octet-stream
[[[base64 encoded contents of the file]]]
.............................103832778631715--
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a mulipart form, don't you?

```
echo Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'files' => true))
```

From http://laravel.com/docs/html

Comment: I don´t think so. Just imagine. something.com/api/v1/get-all service called and response should be in format mentioned above. echo Form generate just form tag if I´m right.

Comment: Aha, so it's sending the response! What about: http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses

Comment: I know about JSON response. In fact I was using JSON  one before noticing that in my project documentation is listed response should be as multipart.

I was thinking about something like
<code>
Route::get('/', function() {
 $headers = array('foo' => 'bar');
 return Response::make('Hello World!', 200, $headers);
});
</code>

Taken from https://tower.la.utexas.edu/index.php/docs/views#downloads

Comment: Just take a look at https://github.com/swt83/laravel-smtp/blob/master/libraries/smtp.php

How they prepare output for e-mail. Pushing header into array than concatenating into one string.

Solution seems to be to return Response::make($headerAsString, 200, $headers); But I want to be sure there is no better and cleaner solution.